# Spring boot with apache cxf not using logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, cxf

I am using apache cxf with spring boot 2.0.4

I have a logback.xml on my classpath and have the following dependencies
 in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.fasterxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.fasterxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.fasterxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.fasterxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${freemarker.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Still for some reason when my app starts I get:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57153', transport: 'socket'
DEBUG StatusLogger org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory is not on classpath. Good!
2018-12-21 16:15:00.136 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.m.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
2018-12-21 16:15:00.154 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
2018-12-21 16:15:00.154 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
2018-12-21 16:15:00.154 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
2018-12-21 16:15:00.154 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
2018-12-21 16:15:00.155 DEBUG [app :: background-preinit::] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-12-21 16:15:01.688 DEBUG [app :: main::] org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils - Using org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger for logging.
2018-12-21 16:15:01.699 DEBUG [app :: main::] o.a.c.c.s.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser - Adding org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.wireBus attribute PROPERTY to bean org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder@9efcd90
2018-12-21 16:15:04.548  INFO [app :: main::] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

And the logs on the console are not exactly what I need.

I am unable to figure out how to exclude apache logging from the dependency.

In a project with so many dependencies I am sure there is a way through dependency management to use the right logging jar. However I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: What is the location of your logback.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the logback dependencies, Just include spring boot starter logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And set the logback version property:

```
<logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
```